# Implementing Workflow async using Core service

Tags: core-service, workflow

I came across following method and trying to use in my application where I am trying to execute a complete workflow using code

`_CoreServiceClient.StartWorkflowAsync("repositoryId", instruction, _ReadOptions);`

I have to put the breakpoint so that my main thread should not complete before async service call but it seems the method is not starting workflow for the bundle as I am unable to see any new activity in CME in Workflow Managment. Am I missing any point?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you put a breakpoint - all of your threads are put on hold, not only the main one. Other than that, your code might exit before the method actually get anywhere. See here for correct usage of the async methods:
http://amarchuk.blogspot.nl/2013/03/asynchronous-operations-with-coreservice.html

You need to make sure that callback is called before you code exit.